# Login_Required is allowing me to access the route without logging in, however I want these routes to be restricted

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

as the title suggests I can access my desired restrictive routes without logging in. How do I make it so I cannot not access this routes without logging in?

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'simple123'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/brendanlydon/Documents/VS_Code_Python/Source/database.db'
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=7, max=100)])
    remember = BooleanField('remember me')

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='Invalid email'), Length(max=50)])
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=7, max=100)])

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/login', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
        return '<h2>Invalid username or password</h2>'
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/sign_up', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def sign_up():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data,first_name=form.first_name.data, 
            last_name=form.last_name.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('sign_up.html', form=form)

@app.route('/home')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', name=current_user.first_name)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('main'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

HTML login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="#">
            <h3 align="center">SourceFin Login</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.remember) }}
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

HTML sign_up.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST">
        <h3 align="center">Sign Up for SourceFin</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.email) }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.first_name) }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.last_name) }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

HTML: home.html

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Everything works. The sign-up page, login page, even the database confirming hashed passwords. But I can access the home.html page without logging in. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

It worked all along the session was just keeping me logged in every time I did not log out before restarting the server.